# Elastic Beanstalk deploy a docker environment from the API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mautic

I am at my whits end trying to solve this problem.  Our ultimate goal is to deploy a custom docker container of Mautic.  I have no problem doing this from their website interface.  I've solved all my config problems and it works great.  But I need to do this automatically from an API.  Customers are going to sign up for our service, and we want to deploy Mautic for them instantly (or as instant as AWS can work).

I'm new to elastic beanstalk and AWS.  But what I understand is I need to create an environment and deploy my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file to it.  But I cannot find anywhere in the API that I can specify a file to deploy or even an S3 bucket to use (like you can from the interface).  I had hoped by saving a template and using that, it would work, but I just get an empty Docker instance with no container launched.

Here's an example of my PHP api call

```
$eb = new ElasticBeanstalkClient(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '...',
        'secret' => '...'
    )
));

$newEnvironment = $eb->createEnvironment(array(
    'ApplicationName' => 'test',
    'TemplateName' => 'foo2',
    'EnvironmentName' => '...',
    'EnvironmentTier' => array(
        'Type' => 'Standard',
        'Name' => 'WebServer'
    ),
    'OptionSettings' => array(
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            'OptionName' => 'EC2KeyName',
            'Value' => '...'
        ],
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName' => 'DBUser',
            'Value' => '...'
        ],
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName' => 'DBPassword',
            'Value' => '...'
        ]
    )
));
```

The template `foo2` was saved from an environment that has a fully running Mautic docker container.

The problem is, this creates an environment and the RDS resource I need, but does not run my docker container.

Is what I want possible?  Or do I have to find another avenue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  What I was looking for was `$eb->createApplicationVersion(...)` which I can use to specify an S3 bucket with my `Dockerrun.aws.json` file. [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html)

Then I can specify that `VersionLabel` in my `createEnvironment()` call like so.

```
$newEnvironment = $eb->createEnvironment(array(
    'ApplicationName' => 'test',
    'TemplateName' => 'foo2',
    // Right here
    'VersionLabel` => 'fooVersion',
    'EnvironmentName' => '...',
    'EnvironmentTier' => array(
        'Type' => 'Standard',
        'Name' => 'WebServer'
    ),
    'OptionSettings' => array(
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
            'OptionName' => 'EC2KeyName',
            'Value' => '...'
        ],
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName' => 'DBUser',
            'Value' => '...'
        ],
        [
            'Namespace' => 'aws:rds:dbinstance',
            'OptionName' => 'DBPassword',
            'Value' => '...'
        ]
    )
));
```

Or I can just create a version through the Dashboard.  [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deployment.html)